# How can I get get a particular piece of data from an email?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

Good morning! I'm trying to automate the process of logging into my email account, accessing the first email there, opening it and retrieving the necessary code. However, I'm not fluent in python/robot framework.

Could I just look for something close to the code I need, save that to a string and then trim it?

Thank you!

Comment: You are not giving enough information, for example, it is important to know what email you are using (POP3 or IMAP or something else). Here is one library that might help you: https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-imaplibrary/

Comment: I was going to the Outlook website and logged in instead of using the library. 
I have implemented the new library, but I get an error when I run the code below!

${new_var}  ImapLibrary.get email body  0

    [Return]    ${new_var}

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'uid'

Comment: Please provide the code on what you did or the logic behind your goals. Please do not expect the whole solutions. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the documentation you need at the [ImapLibrary](https://rickypc.github.io/robotframework-imaplibrary/doc/ImapLibrary.html). The keyword Get Email Body should do the job. After that you can use String Library to manipulate the body you saved in the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

I used the keyword 'Get Text', stored it into a variable, converted the content into a list, trimmed said list in specific hard-coded positions and then converted it back to a string. That did the job.

Code (Probably not the best way to go about it)

```
${email_Body} =         Login To Outlook Automation Email   ${email_User}   ${email_Password}
    @{characters}           Split String To Characters      ${email_Body}

    ${system}=    Evaluate    platform.system()    platform

    IF          "${characters}[0]".upper() == "C" and "${system}".upper() != "LINUX"
        ${x} =  Get Slice From List     ${characters}   517       523   #CAUTION: This email originated from outside the Rail Delivery Group email system. DO NOT click links or open attachments unless you recognise the sender and know the content is safe.
    ELSE IF     "${characters}[0]".upper() == "T" and "${system}".upper() != "LINUX"
        ${x} =  Get Slice From List     ${characters}   385       391   #This Message originated outside your organization.
    ELSE IF     "${characters}[0]".upper() == "C" and "${system}".upper() == "LINUX"
        ${x} =  Get Slice From List     ${characters}   512       529
    ELSE IF     "${characters}[0]".upper() == "Y" and "${system}".upper() != "LINUX"    #QA Outlook Windows
        ${x} =  Get Slice From List     ${characters}   315       321
    ELSE        #QA Outlook Linux
        ${x} =  Get Slice From List     ${characters}   310       316
    END

    ${verification_Code_CRM} =  Evaluate  "".join($x)
    log to console    The code is: '${verification_Code_CRM}'
```